# TryInto trait asks for more type annotations even though all annotations are in place

Tags: rust, enums, type-annotation, enum-dispatch

I have the following code (constrained example). There is a serial protocol, modelled with `Command` and `Responce` enums using `enum_dispatch` crate - every variant in enum is represented with a struct. `Transport` struct taskes care of serialization, execution and deserialization of `Command`s, returning `TransportResult`s back with generic `Responce` enum(generic impl) or specific struct(templated impl). The generic implementation works just fine, but the templated one fails to compile.

```rust
use enum_dispatch::enum_dispatch;
use thiserror::Error;

trait Value{/**/}
trait CommandResponce {type Responce}

#[enum_dipatch(Value)]
enum Command{
    Cmd1(Cmd1)
    // ...
}

struct Cmd1{}
impl Value for Cmd1{ /**/ }

#[enum_dipatch(Value)]
enum Responce{
    Resp1(Resp1)
     // ...
}

struct Resp1{}
impl Value for Resp1{/**/}

impl CommandResponce for Cmd1{ type Responce=Resp1 }

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum ProtocolError{/**/}
type ProtocolResult<T> = Result<T, ProtocolError>;

struct Transport {/**/}
impl Transport {
    // generic
    pub fn command_generic_with_addr(
            &mut self, addr: &mut u8, c: Command
    ) -> ProtocolResult<Responce>{ /**/ }

    // templated
    pub fn command_with_addr<T: SerializeCommand + CommandResponce>(
        &mut self, addr: &mut u8, c: T) -> ProtocolResult<T::Responce>
    where 
        Command: From<T>, Responce: TryInto<T::Responce, Error=&'static str>, 
        Responce: TryInto<T::Responce, Error= CommandErrors> {
        let resp: Responce = self.command_generic_with_addr(addr, Command::from(c))?;
        let ret: T::Responce =  resp.try_into()?;
        Ok(ret)
    }
}


fn main() -> eyre::Result<()>{
   let t = Transport::new();
   let addr : u8 = 0xFF;
   t.command_with_addr(&mut addr, Cmd1{/**/})
}
```

When I try to compile code, identical to the one above, I get the following error:

```
error[E0284]: type annotations needed: cannot satisfy `<Responce as TryInto<<T as CommandResponce>::Responce>>::Error == _`
  --> 
   |
85 |         let ret: T::Responce = match resp.try_into()  {
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^ cannot satisfy `<Responce as TryInto<<T as CommandResponce>::Responce>>::Error == _`
```

I can't understand, what is the error here - I thought I've stated all the neccessary type annotations in the `Transport::command_with_addr` member function.

Note, `enum_dispatch` uses the following code to generate `try_into` conversion, used in the code above:

```
impl #impl_generics core::convert::TryInto<#variant_type> for #enumname #ty_generics #where_clause {
   type Error = &'static str;
   fn try_into(self) -> ::core::result::Result<#variant_type, <Self as core::convert::TryInto<#variant_type>>::Error> {
       //..
   }
}
```